# SQL: SUM function not returning results as I expect

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a set of payment data with vendor, invoice and amount fields. A single payment can have multiple invoices associated with it. I want to get a SUM of the amount, discount, and netpayment for the payment. The query I have works well for one payment but for the other payment it returns separate records corresponding to each invoice.

Desired Result

[image: DisiredResult]

Current Result

[image: Current Result]

Here is the query

```
SELECT
  Payment,
  Vendor,
  SUM(Amount) AS AmountTotal,
  SUM(Discount) AS DiscountTotal,
  SUM(Amount) - SUM(Discount) AS NetPaymentTotal
FROM
  PaymentInfo
GROUP BY
  Payment, Vendor, Amount, Discount;
```

I have also created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/50706/2) to demonstrate the problem.

Payment 5000002 works fine, but payment 5000005 does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `amount` and `discount` from the `group by`:

```
SELECT
  Payment,
  Vendor,
  SUM(Amount) AS AmountTotal,
  SUM(Discount) AS DiscountTotal,
  SUM(Amount) - SUM(Discount) AS NetPaymentTotal
FROM
  PaymentInfo
GROUP BY
  Payment, Vendor;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you include `amount` in the `group by` clause, you are segregating it according to the `account`'s also. As the `amount` with `vendor` '5000002' is same, you are not getting difference for that `vendor`. Unlike for the other `vendor`, where the `amount`'s have been different, you are getting two rows for each of the amount as the group.

So, if you remove `account` from the `group by` clause, you'll get the desired result.